403 forbidden shopify storefront api in my React js project
I am getting a POST 403 (forbidden) error message for fetching data for my single product page however for my product list page, the fetch function work perfectly fine. Please can someone tell me what is going on.
shopifyApi.jsx (imported into Products.jsx):
export const fetchProducts = async () => {
  const response = await fetch(`https://<MyShopifyStore/>.myshopify.com/api/2024-10/graphql.json`, {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'X-Shopify-Storefront-Access-Token': ''
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({
      query: `
        {
          products(first: 5) {
            edges {
              node {
                id
                title
                descriptionHtml
                images(first: 1) {
                  edges {
                    node {
                      src
                    }
                  }
                }
                variants(first: 1) {
                  edges {
                    node {
                      priceV2 {
                        amount
                      }
                    }
                  }
                } 
              }
            }
          }
        }
      `,
    }),
  });

  const { data } = await response.json();
  return data.products.edges;
};

Products.jsx (fetch and display works fine):
import { fetchProducts } from '../../../api/shopifyApi.js'

const Products = () => {
  const [productsList, setProductsList] = useState([]);
  
  useEffect(() => {
    const getProducts = async () => {
      const productData = await fetchProducts();
      setProductsList(productData)
    };
    getProducts();
  }, []);
  
  return (
    <div className="product-container">
      <div className='product-grid'>
      {
        productsList.map(({ node }) => (
          <div
            className='product-card' 
            key={node.id}
          >
            <Link
              to={`/product/${node.productId}`}
              reloadDocument
            >
              {node.images.edges.length > 0 && (
                <img 
                  src={node.images.edges[0].node.src} 
                  alt={node.title} 
                  width={300}
                />
              )}
              {/* <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: node.descriptionHtml }} /> */}
              <h2>{node.title}</h2>
            </Link>
            <p>£{node.variants.edges[0].node.priceV2.amount}</p>
            <button type='button'>ADD TO CART</button>
          </div>
        ))
      }
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Products

ProductPage.jsx (for some reason, doesn't work and gets POST 403 (forbidden):
const ProductPage = () => {
  const { productId } = useParams();
  const [product, setProduct] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchProduct = async () => {
      const response = await fetch(`https://<MyShopifyStore/>.myshopify.com/api/2024-10/graphql.json`, {
        method: 'POST',
        header: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          'X-Shopify-Storefront-Access-Token': ''
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
          query: `
            query {
              product(id: "gid//shopify/Product/${productId}") {
                edges {
                  node {
                    id
                    title
                    descriptionHtml
                    images(first: 1) {
                      edges {
                        node {
                          src
                        }
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          `
        })
      })

      const { data } = await response.json();
      setProduct(data?.product?.edges)
    };

    fetchProduct();
  }, [productId])

  if (!product) return <div>Loading...</div>

  return (
    <div className='product-page-container'>
      <h1>{product.title}</h1>
      {product.images.edges.length > 0 && (
        <img src={product.images.edges[0].node.src} alt={product.title} />
      )}
      <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: product.descriptionHtml }}/>
    </div>
  )
}

export default ProductPage;

The Products.jsx page shows the products but the ProductPage.jsx page gives an error. What am I doing wrong? Please can someone help. Thank you.

A bit late, but if don't get a solution yet...
You're using "edges" field inside your single product query. This query is flat, like:
// Edit
body: JSON.stringify({
  query: `
    query getProduct($productId: ID!) {
      product(id: $productId) {
        id
        title
        descriptionHtml
        images(first: 1) {
          edges {
            node {
              src
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  `,
  variables: {
    productId: `gid://shopify/Product/${productId}`
  }
})

And, as a tip, on StorefrontAPI, prefer "handle" field to query a product instead of its id.

Thank you for this but unfortunately it didn't work, although I have changed the function around and I am no longer getting the 403 (forbidden) error anymore but the products still are not showing.

Oh, I didn't notice was variable query was wrong. You'll need to inform its field on fetch body. I updated the query to the correct one

Thank you again but i figured it out in the end. The problem was with my first query as well. You have to add handle to the fetchProducts query to identify the products SEO, then for fetchProduct you have to add handle as a parameter, then in the graphql query, pass the handle parameter into the query and then return (using useParams) within a useEffect function in the ProductPage. Thank you again for your help though @Zeindelf. I hope I made sense of that.
